# Хозяин и мастер

Tags: значение-слов

Интересно. В том же английском языке слово Master употребляется в значении "хозяин", а в русском — как правило, в значении "специалист", "профессионал", есть даже слово "мастерить", то есть, что-то делать своими руками. То есть, значение фактически противоположное. Как так получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Англии мастер-ремесленник был хозяином своей мастерской, в России же ремесленник - лицо, как правило, подневольное и появится такому значению не с чего. Хотя надо отметить мастер в значении старший, главный мне встречалось, правда вызвано это значение было по всей видимости названием должности.